# Chair on Tisha'bav

Tags: riddle, fast-days, tisha-bav, standing-sitting

Who must sit on a chair on Tishbav?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ashkenazi Shul the person getting Hagbah.

Answer (score 8):

The sandak, if a bris takes place in the morning (as per the first custom cited in Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 559:7).

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who'll be in danger if he doesn't.